# Why does my font behave like this

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making small android app and in every page my font looks like this :
[image]

This is just snippet of screen shot. You can see white colour around letters and I didn't put any of CSS rules for that. It may look like it is ok now but it is realy hard to read on phone. Can I somehow overwrite this rule or have to completly remove it? I am using latest versions of PhoneGap and jquery mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by `text-shadow` property of CSS which jQM uses extensively. You will have to add these lines after you include jQM's css in a `style` tag or something :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
  body .ui-body-c, body .ui-overlay-c { text-shadow:0 0 0; }
</style>
```